# Overlapped Canvas Tooltip

Tags: wpf, canvas, path, tooltip

I have a WPF window where i have more canvas overlapped. Each canvas contains a specific path. On hover over each path i want to see a tooltip with details about that path. Imagine a rectangle cut in 2, each half will be a path in a canvas.

The problem is that because all the canvases are in the same position, one on top of the other, the tooltip for the canvas below will never appear. If i will set IsHitTestVisible as false on all canvas objects, the tooltip will not work anymore, neither for the most top canvas.

Here is the code i am using to create the path with tooltip:

```
                Path path = new Path();
                path.Data = pathGeo;
                path.Fill = Brushes.Yellow;

                var sheetTooltip = new SheetTooltipView();
                path.SetValue(ToolTipService.ToolTipProperty, sheetTooltip);
                path.SetValue(ToolTipService.ShowDurationProperty, 20000);
```

Comment: Put all Paths in one common Canvas?

Comment: Yeah, that was one of my solutions, but for that one i had to change a lot the implementation. I also succeed with more canvases using the IsHitTestVisible property for some of them. Thank you for your answer